# Why does my loaded texture image lose its shininess in three.js

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

Why does my loaded texture image lose its shininess in three.js?

My code is

```
for(var i=0;i<No_of_mat;i++){
    material[i] = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('Image'+i+'.jpg'),shininess:500 });
}

for(var i=0; i<No_of_cubes; i++){
  cube[i] = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(length, width,height),material[RandomNumFromNToM(-0,7)]);

  cube[i].overdraw = true;
  cube[i].position.x=-(5*50) + i*50+40;
  scene.add(cube[i]);
  objects.push( cube[i]);
}
```

But the shininess is ignored.

Also, I'd like to know how to make objects shinier (in real time).

Comment: Are you using `CanvasRenderer`?

Comment: I am using following code for renderer..

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
 renderer.render(scene, camera);

Comment: i did like below

var renderer=new THREE.CanvasRenderer({antialias:true});
renderer.render(scene,camera);

but it is also same effect.